# How to increase writing speed of Neo4j Graph DB?

Tags: neo4j

I have got server with the following properties;

- Memory: `16GB`
- CPU: `8 Cores`
- SSD: `500GB`
- OS: `Windows Server 2012 R2 package`

I'm trying to build graph database of `DBpedia`, approximately it has `580M` of triples. Thus, DB will has nearly `500M nodes` and `700-800M relationships`. 
For the configuration I did the followings:

- neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory = `2000M`
- neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory = `3000M`
- neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory = `1000M`
- dbms.pagecache.memory = `5000M`
- -Xmx = `4000M`

**It reads  ~4000 triples in a second**. How I can increase the performance?

Comment: It looks like you're using an old version of Neo4j (since settings like neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory have been deprecated). You should try the most recent version which is supposed to have better write throughput I think.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to import data quickly into a **new** neo4j DB is to use [the neo4j-import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html).

Comment: This is great advice, though I would also mention that if the DB isn't new that `LOAD CSV` is a good second choice.  Of course, for both your data needs to be in CSV format (for `neo4j-import` it needs to be in a very specific, though not complicated format).  Otherwise it depends on how you're importing data.  If it's with Cypher queries you can batch those via the Transaction JSON endpoint

Comment: Also, of course, the DBpedia import is territory which has been tread before: https://github.com/kbastani/neo4j-dbpedia-importer